# Python / list Как добавить имя в список?

Tags: python, list

Как в пустой лист `[ ]` добавить имя?

```
guests = [ ]

name = ( )
guests = str[input("Enter guest name: ")]
```

Выдает:

> File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'Rene' is not defined

Comment: Python 2 используете?

Comment: да,  2.7 - Pycharm

Comment: Всё-таки кто-то должен, проходя мимо вопроса, посоветовать переходить на 3.6, так как поддержка 2.7 заканчивается в 2020 году :)

Comment: спасибо, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 3):

1. Во втором питоне `input()` работает не так, как в третьем. Во втором питоне `input()` пытается исполнить введённую строку, как код.

Чтобы просто сохранить введённую строку в переменную, во втором питоне используйте `raw_input()`.

2. Квадратные скобки в последней строке вызовут ошибку. Чтобы добавить что-то в существующий список, используйте метод `.append`

В итоге ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
guests = []
guests.append(raw_input("Enter guest name: "))
```

Comment: спасибо большое!